# how to connect a docker container to network

Tags: linux, docker

I am newbie to docker.

i am running a docker container with ip address 172.17.0.5 at Host 192.168.1.231 Ubuntu OS .
when i ping 172.17.0.5 from 192.168.1.231 it ping successful. but another host at network with ip 192.168.1.190 is not able to ping 172.17.0.5.

i add nat rule also at 192.168.1.231

```
*nat
-I PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.231 ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "docker_dnat_76b3de111215" -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.5:80
COMMIT
```

now docker container ping all node on network successfully..
how can i visible docker container on network..?
please help

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making the container available on the network, it would be better to persist the data on the host and to expose the IP address(es) needed for the service that you are running in the container. For example, if you have MySQL in your container, you would expose the port 3306 and bind it to the same port or any port you choose on the host so that the database is accessible from the host. The other thing that you would do would be to persist the data and mount the volume inside your container so that MySQL will use that to write to; persisting the data to the host in between restarts or if you shutdown the container.